# Group the elements in a list of lists into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following sample list of lists (only a section is shown):

```
[
["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "s35"], 
["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH",], 
["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", "s55"], 
["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW"], 
["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", "s35", "cWW"], 
["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", "s35"]
....
]
```

I would like to group the elements in this list into a nested dictionary based on the following list of keys:

```
outer_key = ["4YBB|1|AA", "4WOI|1|DA"]
inner_key = [(259, 267), (259, 260), (260, 261), (260, 265), (260, 267), (261, 263), (261, 264), (262, 263), (264, 265), (265, 267)]
```

As you can notice, the outer key represents a subset of the element at index [0] and index [1] of the inner list whereas the inner key tuple values represent the last element of the index [0] and index [1] of the inner list when split using the '|' character. The inner key tuples represent all the possible combination of positions (x,y) that might have an 'interaction' (index[2] onwards of the inner list). As such, not all keys will have a value associated with it. If a particular inner tuple key is not present, append the "-" to its value.

```
pw_info = {
 "4YBB|1|AA" : {

            (259, 267): "cWW",
            (259, 260): "-",
            (260, 261): "-",
            (260, 265): "-",
            (260, 267): "-",
            (261, 263): "tSH",
            (261, 264): "ntSH;s55",
            (262, 263): "s35",
            (264, 265): "-",
            (265, 267): "s35"

           },

 "4WOI|1|DA" : {

            (259, 267): "-",
            (259, 260): "-",
            (260, 261): "-",
            (260, 265): "-",
            (260, 267): "-",
            (261, 263): "-",
            (261, 264): "-",
            (262, 263): "s35;cWW",
            (264, 265): "s35",
            (265, 267): "-"

            }            
}
```

The keys must be ordered according to the outer and the inner key lists. Also, it is possible for the inner list to have more than 3 elements. If there are more than 3 elements, concatenate element at index [2] and higher together using ";" as the inner dictionary value (for example: (261, 264): "ntSH;s55" ). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where does some of the empty items i.e. (260, 261): "-"  come from?  I don't see those in the initial list of lists?

Comment: @dasvootz Some of the inner lists have these combinations of tuple values. I'm not showing all to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for "*The keys must be ordered according to the outer and the inner key lists*" - keep in mind that dictionaries are unordered data structures.
 `OrderedDict` object is an alternative.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pprint

input_list = [
    ["4YBB|1|AA|A|262", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "s35"],
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|A|263", "tSH", ],
    ["4YBB|1|AA|U|261", "4YBB|1|AA|C|264", "ntSH", "s55"],
    ["4YBB|1|AA|G|259", "4YBB|1|AA|C|267", "cWW"],
    ["4WOI|1|DA|A|262", "4WOI|1|DA|A|263", "s35", "cWW"],
    ["4WOI|1|DA|C|264", "4WOI|1|DA|G|265", "s35"]
]

outer_keys = ["4YBB|1|AA", "4WOI|1|DA"]
inner_keys = [(259, 267), (259, 260), (260, 261), (260, 265), (260, 267),
             (261, 263), (261, 264), (262, 263), (264, 265), (265, 267)]

# prepopulated dict indexed by `outer_keys` and 
# containing OrderedDicts with default values for `inner_keys`  
pw_info = {k: OrderedDict({t: '-' for t in inner_keys}) for k in outer_keys}

for sub_lst in input_list:
    # extract starting slice from first 2 items (like `4YBB|1|AA`)
    k0, k1 = sub_lst[0][:9], sub_lst[1][:9]
    # check if 2 slices are equal and contained in `pw_info` dict (i.e. `outer_keys`)
    if k0 == k1 and k0 in pw_info:
        v1, v2 = sub_lst[0], sub_lst[1]
        # `sub_key` is aimed to be a key for inner dict of the predefined `pw_info` dict
        # thus it's composed as a tuple of trailing numbers of the first 2 items
        # in sub_list (ex. `(262, 263)`)
        sub_key = (int(v1[v1.rfind('|')+1:]), int(v2[v2.rfind('|')+1:]))
        pw_info[k0][sub_key] = sub_lst[2] if len(sub_lst) == 3 else ';'.join(sub_lst[2:])

pprint.pprint(pw_info)
```

The output:

```
{'4WOI|1|DA': OrderedDict([((259, 267), '-'),
                           ((259, 260), '-'),
                           ((260, 261), '-'),
                           ((260, 265), '-'),
                           ((260, 267), '-'),
                           ((261, 263), '-'),
                           ((261, 264), '-'),
                           ((262, 263), 's35;cWW'),
                           ((264, 265), 's35'),
                           ((265, 267), '-')]),
 '4YBB|1|AA': OrderedDict([((259, 267), 'cWW'),
                           ((259, 260), '-'),
                           ((260, 261), '-'),
                           ((260, 265), '-'),
                           ((260, 267), '-'),
                           ((261, 263), 'tSH'),
                           ((261, 264), 'ntSH;s55'),
                           ((262, 263), 's35'),
                           ((264, 265), '-'),
                           ((265, 267), '-')])}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Would you mind explaining the logic about the sub_key part before I accept this answer? Thanks

Comment: @TheEmperor, welcome, I've added explanation through comments